# ShowCaseView Target from another Layout

Tags: android, r.java-file

My Main Activity Inflate the activity_main.xml

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

in this activity main i have RecyclerView View:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/readList"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_below="@+id/layoutListarSpiner"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

for the RecyclerView items i have another layout, the recycleritemlist that are inflated from the Adapter:

```
public MyCustomHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.recycleritemlist, viewGroup, false);

        return new MyCustomHolder(itemView);
    }
```

and inside this recyclerviewlist i have a ImageButton that i want to set the ShowCaseView to point:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="38dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/favorite"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />
```

but the ShowCaseView keep showing me NULL POINTER:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.getLocationInWindow(int[])' on a null object reference
```

thats because the R.id.status is returning NULL

```
 ViewTarget target = new ViewTarget(R.id.status, main);
```

the ShowCaseCode to Highlight

```
 ViewTarget target = new ViewTarget(R.id.status, main);

        new ShowcaseView.Builder(main)
                .setTarget(target)
                .setContentTitle("Test 1 - Status")
                .setContentText("This is the Status BUTTON")
                .hideOnTouchOutside()
                .build();

    }
```

how can i make the R.id.status acessible/not null?

Comment: When are you calling showcaseview to display the tutorial ? Your ViewTarget might allways return null if the view is not created yest.

Comment: @Nicolas how i cant not be created since the RecyclerVIew is populated?

Comment: the showcaseview might be called before your adapter inflate the list item view

Comment: @Nicolas, not worked too, the problem is, the Main Activity call the Adapter, inside the Adapter class it inflate the row for the RecyclerView with the textview, BUT from the MainActivity i need to "catch" this created row with textview, i tried inflating it again in MainActivity, but no results too